# Herança em Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

Tabela:

> Serviços (tabela Servicos) - com as propriedades em comum de todos os serviços + Type + ServiceID

Tabela:

> Serviço 1 (tabela Servico1) - com as propriedades do serviço 1

Tabela:

> Serviço 2 (tabela Servico2) - com as propriedades do serviço 2

Porém, eu preciso guardar, na tabela de Serviços, informações como "Tipo de Serviço" e "Id do Serviço".

Basicamente, se for cadastrado um Serviço 2, será criado um registro tbm na tabela Servicos com o "Tipo do Serviço = Servico 2" e "Id do Serviço = Servico_ID (da tabela Servico2)".

Como eu consigo representar isso com as entidades no Entity Framework?

Comment: Exemplo: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: Exemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618293(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Exemplo: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/04/14/tip-12-how-to-choose-an-inheritance-strategy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente um conselho, tente estudar as diferenças entre `TPH`, `TPC` e `TPT`, para que possa escolher a melhor opção para cada cenário.

- `TPH` - Tabela por Hieraquia - Terá uma unica tabela para todas as Entidades.
- `TPC` - Tabela por Concreto - Terá uma tabela para cada tipo concreto.
- `TPT` - Tabela por Tipo - Terá uma tabela para cada tipo (abstrato ou concreto).

No seu caso em especifico, lhe aconselho à tornar `Servico` uma classe abstrata, para impedir que à mesma seja instanciada.

Por exemplo, pense nas entidades `Pessoa`, `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`, enquanto é interessante ter a habilidade de consultar todas as pessoas. É importante que o usuário sempre cadastre uma `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica`.

agora vou postar a implementação para cada estrategia.:

**`TPT` - Tabela por Tipo**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServicoA> ServicosA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServicoB> ServicosB { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

[Table("Servicos")]
public abstract class Servico
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ServicoID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

[Table("ServicosA")]
public class ServicoA : Servico
{
    public decimal ValorA { get; set; }
}

[Table("ServicosB")]
public class ServicoB : Servico
{
    public decimal ValorB { get; set; }
}
```

**`TPH` - Tabela por Hieraquia**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServicoA> ServicosA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServicoB> ServicosB { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

[Table("Servicos")]
public abstract class Servico
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ServicoID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

public class ServicoA : Servico
{
    public decimal ValorA { get; set; }
}

public class ServicoB : Servico
{
    public decimal ValorB { get; set; }
}
```

Note à remoção do atributo `[Table]` das entidades `ServicoA` e `ServicoB`.

**`TPC` - Tabela por Concreto**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ServicoA> ServicosA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServicoB> ServicosB { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public abstract class Servico
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ServicoID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

[Table("ServicosA")]
public class ServicoA : Servico
{
    public decimal ValorA { get; set; }
}

[Table("ServicosB")]
public class ServicoB : Servico
{
    public decimal ValorB { get; set; }
}
```

Note que a entidade `Servico` não é mais mapeada.

Por fim, vou colocar o script gerado pelo Migrations para cada uma das situações acima.:

**`TPT` - Tabela por Tipo**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Servicos] (
    [ServicoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Servicos] PRIMARY KEY ([ServicoID])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServicosA] (
    [ServicoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ValorA] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ServicosA] PRIMARY KEY ([ServicoID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ServicoID] ON [dbo].[ServicosA]([ServicoID])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServicosB] (
    [ServicoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ValorB] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ServicosB] PRIMARY KEY ([ServicoID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ServicoID] ON [dbo].[ServicosB]([ServicoID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServicosA] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ServicosA_dbo.Servicos_ServicoID] FOREIGN KEY ([ServicoID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Servicos] ([ServicoID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ServicosB] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ServicosB_dbo.Servicos_ServicoID] FOREIGN KEY ([ServicoID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Servicos] ([ServicoID])
```

**`TPH` - Tabela por Hieraquia**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Servicos] (
    [ServicoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [nvarchar](max),
    [ValorA] [decimal](18, 2),
    [ValorB] [decimal](18, 2),
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Servicos] PRIMARY KEY ([ServicoID])
)
```

**`TPC` - Tabela por Concreto**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServicosA] (
    [ServicoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ValorA] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ServicosA] PRIMARY KEY ([ServicoID])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServicosB] (
    [ServicoID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ValorB] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ServicosB] PRIMARY KEY ([ServicoID])
)
```

Por fim, note que a estrategia `TPC` é mais limitada que as outras duas. Por exemplo, se quiser buscar todos os serviços, terá de fazer uma união entre as duas coleções.

Já à escolha entre à `TPH` e à `TPT`, é um trade-off entre quantidade de colunas à serem recuperadas do banco (`TPH` traz tudo) e o custo para realizar `JOINS`(no caso do `TPT`, será necessário JOINs entre as tabelas, e isto tem um custo, possivelmente um índice se tornará necessário).

Apesar de não existir uma bala de prata para qual estrategia escolher, se o banco for ser manipulado apenas pela sua solução (sem intervenção humana direto no Banco de Dados), eu diria para ficar com à `TPH`, pois está terá um desempenho superior quando comparada à `TPT`.

E quanto à sua duvida com delete, ao apagar uma entidade do Tipo `ServicoB`, serão apagados os registros nas tabelas `Servicos` e `ServicosB`, e por fim, um registro na tabela `Servicos`, sempre terá um registro filho na tabela `ServicosA` ou na tabela `ServicosB`, porém jamais nas duas.

Comment: Na Herança `TPT` só tem a classe Base dentro do `DbContext` e as operações serão feitas por ela, observe alguns links: [link1](https://ferhenriquef.com/2012/06/11/mapeando-heranas-no-entity-framework-code-first/) e [link2](http://www.macoratti.net/11/12/ef4_tph1.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Não sou especialista em EF, mas para esse cenário existe o mapenamento chamado *Table-per-Type (TPT)* que parece bem com o que você precisa.

Cada entidade é mapeada para uma tabela.

Exemplo:

```
public class Servico
{
   [Key]
   public int ServicoId { get; set; }
   public string Tipo { get; set; }
}

public class Servico1 : Servico
{
    //com as propriedades do serviço 1
}

public class Servico2: Servico
{
   //com as propriedades do serviço 1
}
```

Mapeando via Code First:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Servico>().ToTable("Servico");
modelBuilder.Entity<Servico1>().ToTable("Servico1");
modelBuilder.Entity<Servico2>().ToTable("Servico2");
```

### Edição

> *Dessa maneira eu havia pensado, mas não tem uma maneira simplificada? Assim, pra fazer um delete, add, update...eu teria que fazer primeiro na "filha" e depois na "mãe". Pra adicionar, teria que adicionar a "filha", retornar o ID criado e criar a "mãe"*

Como as tabelas/objetos estão associados você não precisa fazer uma operação para cada objeto.

//Add

```
context.Servico.Add(new Servico1
{
    //com as propriedades do serviço 2
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

O código acima o EF vai criar um insert para as duas tabelas (Servico e Servico1).

Da mesma forma, no caso de Update ou Delete, o EF sabe qual coluna é de qual tabela e faz atualização ou Delete para você.

//Delete

```
var primeiroService = context.Service.FirstOrDefault();
if (primeiroService != null)
{
    context.Service.Remove(primeiroService);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

No código acima o EF vai criar um delete para as duas tabelas (Servico e Servico1) pois como as tabelas estão relacionadas ele sabe qual registro excluir.

Comment: Dessa maneira eu havia pensado, mas não tem uma maneira simplificada? Assim, pra fazer um delete, add, update...eu teria que fazer primeiro na "filha" e depois na "mãe". Pra adicionar, teria que adicionar a "filha", retornar o ID criado e criar a "mãe".